# DJICrashHandler handled my RuntimeException and gave no useful instruction to solve it

Tags: dji-sdk

App crashed and DJICrashHandler just handled the exception, showing these useless logs at logical below:
[DJICrashHandler:uncaughtException3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8OQw.jpg)

I just can't get any useful information (such as RuntimeException type, position in code) from those logs! It is so annoying that I have to use my own CrashHandler to generate a log file on my phone and open it to get the Exception log. Nearly all those Exceptions are none of DJI's business.

Do something, please!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the crash logs the SDK saves to the device?

There should be a log file in the device under the folder: DJI\\LOG\CRASH